# How many *Non-Native* speakers of Egyptian Arabic are there world wide?

Tags: data-request, language

Every time I try to look this up, it always gives me the number for native speakers. I'm not looking for that. I specifically want to know **how prevalent Egyptian Arabic is as a second language around the world**. Only 68% of Egyptian citizens speak Egyptian Arabic natively but the other 32% have to have some kind of fluency in it, right? Not to mention, Egyptian Arabic is often the language used in Arabic movies, tv shows, and books. So there's a lot of people in the Arab world who have learned Egyptian Arabic as a second language.

Every article I find states that Egyptian Arabic is spoken in Iraq, Israel, Jordan, Kuwait, Libya, Saudi Arabia, United Arab Emirates, and Yemen, but they never specify how many people in those countries speak it. I've also tried looking at the demographics for some of those countries and they almost never mention Egyptian Arabic. The closest I got was a demographic chart that said roughly 600,000 of Saudi Arabians speak Egyptian Arabic but that was only counting. *Egyptian immigrants to the country and not the people in Saudi Arabia who learned it as a second language.* I'm looking for L2 speakers of Egyptian Arabic, not native speakers who have moved to other countries. I'm not sure where else to look, so I came here hoping someone would either know the answer or know a good place to look.